# What is the recommended way of accessing a network share folder (located in Windows or Linux) in java

Tags: java, linux, suse

All, Forgive me I am not familiar with the Linux. 
I am trying to read all the files of a network share folder which is located in either Windows or Linux system.

Currently I just made it work for the case of Windows by below code.

```
networkShareFolder="\\\\10.50.90.18\\ITS Tool\\xml\\";//It is a windows Network share path.
File[] files = new File(networkShareFolder).listFiles();
```

But When I deploy my application to the Linux system and run it. It just told me can not get any files from the specified `networkShareFolder`;

So I tried to type the path `\\10.50.90.18` in the File explorer of Linux like what I did in the windows. To see if the path can be reached from the Linux system. But it just told me `Can't locate the \\10.50.90.18`. But I am sure the IP can be ping from the Linux.

So my questions are

1. Why `\\10.50.90.18` can't be accessed in Linux .But can be accessed in Windows. (I am sure their IP are all 10.50.90.*)
2. What is the best way to access the network share folder from windows or linux ?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you ping 10.50.90.18 from the Linux machine? Do you have samba installed?

Comment: I believe Linux doesn't allow you to access UNC directly like that.  Either you mount that path and access just like a local directory, or you may make use of smbclient if you do not like to mount it.  Or a more portable way, use a plain Java SMB client (e.g. JCIFS?) to access so that you do not need to rely on OS-specific features

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Yes, I can ping the IP. the Samba? I am not sure about that . How to verify to it ? Thanks.

Comment: @AdrianShum OK. SMB. Execute me . Does the SMB is just the another name of samba? Thanks.

Comment: SMB is, in short, the protocol name.  Samba is the product on Linux that implements SMB with different utilties

Comment: @AdrianShum aha . Good . Well explain. :)

Answer (score 15):

### Remote Mount with FUSE

It's possible to mount a remote filesystem (generally including SMB/CIFS) with [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/) and [samba](https://www.samba.org/). That might look something like (assuming you have a mountpoint `/windows`)

```
# export USER=efrisch
# export WORKGRP=mygrp
# smbmount //10.50.90.18/ /windows –o username=$USER,workgroup=$WORKGRP
```

Then you could access your directory (transparently) with

```
new File("/windows/ITS Tool/xml")
```

### Pure Java Solution (with JCIFS)

[JCIFS](https://jcifs.samba.org/) provides [`SmbFile`](https://jcifs.samba.org/src/docs/api/jcifs/smb/SmbFile.html) and that provides [`listFiles()`](https://jcifs.samba.org/src/docs/api/jcifs/smb/SmbFile.html#listFiles%28%29) allowing something like

```
SmbFile[] files = new SmbFile("smb://10.50.90.18/ITS Tool/xml/").listFiles();
```

The linked documentation for `SmbFile` does give the full format as

> smb://[[[domain;]username[:password]@]server[:port]/[[share/[dir/]file]]][?param=value[param2=value2[...]]]

and it also notes that *all SMB URLs that represent workgroups, servers, shares, or directories require a trailing slash '/'.*

Comment: Nice . Sounds I have two options to make it . Well . I think I need to do more research based on your answer .em.. That is good point to get start. Thank you .

Comment: I am sorry . I don't why , I can't access the path `smb://10.50.90.18` in my Linux(alt+f2 run windows). Nothing to do with the Java. Thanks.