# Pass external windows path in weblogic hosted properties file to my application

Tags: java, windows, unix, weblogic

I have a very old legacy application in which I have been asked to add some simple functionality. This has lead me to include in my external properties file a path in which a file will be placed and picked up from. The path where I want to drop the file is located on a windows server not on the UNIX Weblogic server that my application and application properties are hosted on.

When running this on my local with the file path of `////MYSERVER//MYFOLDER` in my properties file, it works fine since it goes through the windows explorer.

However, once we deploy to our DEV environment on the weblogic unix server it is creating a folder named  `//MYSERVER/MYFOLDER` right on the UNIX server and not realizing that it should be making a reference to a separate server.

Is there any way for my application to realize that this should be referenced as an external server and place the file there?

Here is how I'm grabbing the variable from the properties file:

```
String attachmentServer = Environment.getValue("attachmentServer");
String attachedfiledir = Environment.getValue("attachedfiledir");
String dirName = attachmentServer+attachedfiledir;
File dir = new File(dirName);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the recommended way of accessing a network share folder (located in Windows or Linux) in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30496635/what-is-the-recommended-way-of-accessing-a-network-share-folder-located-in-wind)

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 possibilities:

1. Use some client library that implements the CIFS/SMB networking
   protocol. With this protocol windows is sharing files in your local
   network. Example: https://jcifs.samba.org/
2. Mount Windows share (folder with property file) on UNIX filesystem (Example https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Mounting_samba_shares_from_a_unix_client).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you mount the SMB windows drive on your unix and access them normally ?

How to Solaris -> [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19120-01/open.solaris/820-2429/mountsharetask/index.html)

How to AIX -> [here](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=isg3T1012550)

How to HP-UX -> [here](http://community.hpe.com/t5/System-Administration/mounting-CIFS-share-on-HP-UX-11i/td-p/3597426)