# Check if file exist on windows from webapp on linux

Tags: java, linux, window, filepath

I migrate a webapp from C# (server windows) to java and deploy it to a linux server.
The webapp has a file-server on windows (shared ip server: \ip\file_path).

Problem is when I using Paths.get(String ip, String directory, String fileName) from webapp on linux, I cannot check if this file exist on windows from linux.
In case file not exist webapp will create a new file and return filepath to client (browser), you know I cannot created file too.

If the file server and webapp are the same OS, it works perfect.
Any idea.
Thank you.

Comment: Your problem sound similar to this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30496635/what-is-the-recommended-way-of-accessing-a-network-share-folder-located-in-wind Hope this helps.

Comment: @user12047085 thank you. But It not my case. ^^